# Cypress test, assertion fail

Tags: cypress

```
then(randomTxt => {
        cy.get('[data-cy="abn-input"]').type(`${randomTxt}`)

      // to do : repeat up to 100 times if ABN is already in use
      
        cy.get('[data-cy="search-button"]').click()
        for(let i = 1; i<100; i++){
        if(cy.get('#mat-error-5')){
          cy.get('[data-cy="abn-input"]').clear()
          cy.get('[data-cy="abn-input"]').type(`${randomTxt}`)
          cy.get('[data-cy="search-button"]').click()
        }else {
          i+=100;
        }
      }
```

hi
I need to make a cypress test, it is for checking available number from the list,
the problem is when the number is available, there is no error message ('#mat-error-5')
it is gone, and the test just fails.
there is no DOM to refer to on the webpage other than this

please help me

Comment: If you are checking if a string/number is currently in use, you can either make the random string/number large so lower the probability of it being used. (ie. Cyprses._.random(1e10))

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do it with `.should()` retry and timeout:

```js
let i = '';

cy.get('[data-cy="abn-input"]', {timeout: 10000})  // time you need goes here
  .clear()
  .type(`${randomTxt}${i}`)
  .get('[data-cy="search-button"]')
  .click()
  .get('#mat-error-5')
  .then(() => { i+=100 })
  .should('not.exist')
```

The `.should('not.exist')` expression has retry for timeout given above.

It may go all the way up the chain to retry from `cy.get('[data-cy="abn-input"]')`, if so this looks simplest.

Note Cypress v12 changed retry mechanism to make better use of the whole chain.

Comment: got assertion error on this code   
.get('#mat-error-5')   
so when the number is available, #mat-error-5 is gone, it is not exist   
it only appears when the number is already in use